# Messaging probabilities

Tags: combinatorics

I am part of a large family - we have twenty-four people who send texts back and forth, in various configurations. What would be the total number of possible message threads? All the different one-on-ones - the three persons groups, four, etc., up to all twenty-four of us on one thread.

Answer (score 2):

$\require{cancel}$

Alternatively, suppose that we have a thread that only $2$ members participate. Because order doesn't matter, we have $\dbinom{24}{2}$ such threads. The number of threads that any $3$ members participate is $\dbinom{24}{3}$. Following the same procedure, we have that the total amount of threads is:
$$\sum_{n=2}^{24} \dbinom{24}{n}=16,777,191,$$
which agrees to ToolPurger's answer.

---

We can work the same way, as we did before. Suppose that we fix a person (yourself), which we want to participate in every thread. Let's begin with the thread with $2$ participants (the one is yourself). Thus, we have to pick the other person from the rest $23$ people. We can do that with $\dbinom{23}{1} = 23$ ways. The number of threads with $2$ people (again, the one is yourself) is $\dbinom{23}{1}$.

Moving to the thread with $3$ participants (the one is yourself) means that we have to pick the $2$ participants from the rest $23$ people. We can do so with $\dbinom{23}{2}$ different ways. That means the number of threads consisting of $3$  people (again, the one is yourself) is $\dbinom{23}{2}$.

Following the same procedure, we have eventually that that number of threads you are included is:
$$\sum_{n=1}^{23}\dbinom{23}{n}=8,388,607.$$

<s>You can do the math</s> .

Comment: OK - that works. Sixteen and three-quarter million. Thanks - very grateful, and the family seems quite impressed.

Comment: BTW - a sub-question just came to me. How many of those could just I be involved in. Since there are twenty-four people, I wonder if the answer is just dividing the total by 24??   Yields about seven hundred thousand - seems quite high - ?

Comment: @Soskoth You will be surprised by the result.

Comment: thanasissdr - I'm positive I'll be surprised by the result, but I'm still a neophyte on this site and haven't been able to find "the result," if you posted it - sorry!

Comment: That works for me. If my possibilities are over eight millions, I'd better get texting!  Thanks for the insight.

Comment: @Soskoth Ahahahaha! Yes, it seems you participate (as every single member of your family)  in a lot of threads! So, you have to do a lot of texting!! You're welcome! :)

Answer (score 0):

If we encode:
$(0110\cdots)$ as 1st member (alphabetical ordering say) not included, 2nd and 3rd included, 4th not, so forth...

Then there are $2^{24}-25$ ways.

$2^{24}$ is the number of such binary strings, and 24 of those are messages to oneself, which we discount, as well as empty threads (messages to no one)

> It is worth noting that the sums of  nCr and 2n are related, in fact:
>   $$\sum^n_{i=0}\ ^nC_i=2^n$$
>   So what this answer has is:
>   $\sum^{24}_{n=2}\ ^{24}C_n=\sum^{24}_{n=0}\ ^{24}C_n -\ ^{24}C_0 - \ ^{24}C_1=2^{24}−1−24=2^{24}−25$ - as I claimed.

Comment: @thanasissdr it's 50. I hope I didn't come across as rude with the edit. I just wanted to be like "it's no coincidence that $2^n$ and $\sum\ ^nC_r$ appears in answers" - I can upvote though!

Comment: @thanasissdr can I have the markup for that comment or is it lost now?

Comment: @thanasissdr I made an edit to your post with a yellowbox showing the relation between our answers. I'd like to add it to mine and not write it out again.

Comment: @thanasissdr thank you for keeping the tab open! I've texed it now. -Moss

Comment: This is a good answer, I maintain my upvote.